# Android studio how to put the logcat window back to original place

Tags: android-studio, logcat, setting

[image]

I have drag the log cat window out of the Main window, how can i put i back.
 I have tried double click the window or do something else. 
but i could not find the right way to put the window back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy. See the picture below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i want to vote you up, but my reputation is not enough.